# Ionic 4 Angular: Is it possible to have a fixed element in content while using infinite refresher?

Tags: html, css, angular, ionic-framework

Consider a simple Ionic page's content:

```
<ion-content>

    <ion-refresher slot="fixed">...</ion-refresher>

    <div *ngFor="let item of items">
        ...
    </div>

    <ion-infinite-scroll>...</ion-infinite-scroll>

</ion-content>
```

I made a Stackblitz to demonstrate this page: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-v4-angular-tabs-nbjk4k

Now I would like to add something with fixed position – let's say `<div>Some content</div>` – on the top or bottom of the page that is NOT within the `ion-header` or `ion-footer` section. Is it possible to fix that `div` to stick to the top or bottom?

The official advice I found on the Ionic docs and Github was to use `slot="fixed"` on any element that I would like to fix in the content area.

It somehow does not work for me, maybe there is a conflict with the `slot="fixed"` of the refresher component.

How can I achieve a fixed element?

Answer (score 4):

Indeed there was an issue with `slot="fixed"`, 
Ionic team did some changes for that.

The content(div?) needs to be wrapped in a position:relative wrapper.
 Use `position:relative` in the tag and it should do the thing. 
For example - `<div slot='fixed' style="position:relative">Some content</div>`.

[Follow this PR](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/17754) for more Info. Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 3):

Link: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/17754

There is a bug on slot="fixed". In order for you to make your desired output, you need to put style="position: relative" as per the discussion above.

I created a simple sample for you below:

```
<ion-content>
<div slot='fixed' style="position:relative">Some content</div>

 <ion-refresher slot="fixed" (ionRefresh)="doRefresh($event)">
  <ion-refresher-content></ion-refresher-content>
 </ion-refresher>

 <div *ngFor="let item of items; let i=index;" class="item">
   Item {{i}}: {{ item }}
 </div>

 <ion-infinite-scroll threshold="100px" (ionInfinite)="loadData($event)">
  <ion-infinite-scroll-content
    loadingSpinner="bubbles"
    loadingText="Loading more data...">
  </ion-infinite-scroll-content>
 </ion-infinite-scroll>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: That works indeed. However, this only allows to put the fixed part on the top. Is it possible on the bottom as well?

Comment: This leads to a UI bug in my example. The refresher is covered by other fixed content. We would need to move the refresher down somehow.

Comment: The known bug is still there using slot="fixed" and swiper...